# How to fix ''error: relation "queList" does no exist" when writing to Postgres DB with deployed env with AWS-Lambda & Typeorm?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, typeorm

I am unable make a POST request for my API that is deployed AWS-Lambda.
When I try on my local machine it works fine.

The techstack I am using is as follows:

- Typescript
- TypeORM
- Serverless with AWS-Lambda
- RDS
- PostgreSQL
- Gitlab CI

When using my local and substituting local DB parameters with the RDS parameters, I am able to make a POST request just fine. It is only when it is deployed via Gitlab CI that it gives me the following error:

`error: relation "queList" does not exist at Connection.parseE (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:555:11)`

Has anyone come across this kind of problem before? I would be grateful if anyone can provide me some directions to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: I'm afraid there is not enough data for us to help you. We have no idea what is your TypeOrm configuration in your lambda function, or the data mapping you use "queList" could be anything for us.

Comment: Thanks for getting back zenbeni... it turned out it was a typo..